# How can I swap two specific elements in an array

Tags: arrays, methods

I need to Write a Java method int[] easyAs123(int[] nums) that takes an array of integers and returns an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 1 and 2 is immediately followed by a 3, in the order of the appearance, as in the test cases below.

Specifically,

1. In the input array, every 1 is always immediately followed by a 2.

2. However, even though every 2 is immediately followed by a number, not every 2 is immediately followed by a 3.

2. Do not move the 1 and 2's, but every other number may move to swap place with a 3.
3. The input array contains the same number of 1's, 2's and 3's.

for example:easyAs123([5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]) → [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

easyAs123([1, 2, 9, 8, 3, 5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 6, 4]) → [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]